# Why is this operator symmetric? A question concerning a paper from Brezis and Crandall

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading the paper [Uniqueness of the initial-value problem $u_t - \Delta \varphi u = 0$](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~brezis/PUBlications/075journal.pdf) by Brezis and Crandall.

At the beginning of the analysis, they introduce an operator $B g$ by 
$$ B g := (\epsilon  - \Delta)^{-1} g$$ 
i.e., $B g$ is the unique solution of 
$$ \epsilon v - \Delta v = g \text{ in the sense of distributions}.$$

After introducing this operator, the authors claim that $B$ is "obviously symmetric".

I don't see this.

**Attempt**

I tried the following formal relations
\begin{align}
\langle f, Bg \rangle &= \epsilon^{-1} \langle f, \epsilon Bg \rangle \\
&= \epsilon^{-1} \langle f, g + \Delta Bg \rangle \\
\langle Bf, g \rangle &= \epsilon^{-1} \langle g, f + \Delta Bf \rangle
\end{align}

Therefore

$$\langle f, Bg \rangle - \langle Bf, g \rangle =\epsilon^{-1} [\langle f, \Delta Bg \rangle - \langle g, \Delta Bf \rangle] $$

I don't see how to show that this difference equals zero.

Comment: The trick is to write $f$ as $(\epsilon-\Delta)Bf$ and then use the symmetry of $\epsilon-\Delta$. This is true under appropriate boundary conditions (I did not look at the precise assumptions on $f$ and $g$ in the article).